# How does one get the UserForm where MSForms.ComboBox Object is located?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Hi got a Class Called "FilterLine", It consist of 3 ComboBoxes which are filled depending on all other already selected filters. Here a simplification of the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Filter As MSForms.Combobox
Public WithEvents Operator As MSForms.Combobox
Public WithEvents Options As MSForms.Combobox
Public index As Integer

' This sub adds a new FilterLine and formats it

Public Sub Add()

' Do Stuff with form in which it is embedded

frmFilter.Height = frmFilter.Height + 50

End Sub

' Other subs
```

Where frmFilter is the Userform. This is rather unelegant since I refer to the userform as a name and therefore the class could not be used without changes in another userform. The Userform should always be the userform where the default filter is located. **But how does one get the userform from a ComboBox?**

For example with a range object you can do this:

```
dim rng as Range

set rng = 'Whatever you want

rng.Worksheet.activate
```

This will activate the worksheet where the range is located. But how does one get the UserForm instance from a MSForms.ComboBox?

Edit:

To clarify I call the Userform using this code:

```
Sub testFilter()
Dim Filterm As FilterModel

Set Filterm = New FilterModel

With New frmFilter
    Set .Model = Filterm
    .SetDefaultFilter' This is the interesting part
    .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Then the UserForm Instance.SetDefaultFilter sets the default filter with:

```
Public Sub SetDefaultFilterLine()

Dim DefaultFilterLine As New FilterLine
Set DefaultFilterLine.Filter = frmFilter.DefaultFilter
Set DefaultFilterLine.Operator = frmFilter.DefaultOperator
Set DefaultFilterLine.Options = frmFilter.DefaultOptions
DefaultFilterLine.index = 1

Me.Model.FilterCol.Add DefaultFilterLine

' This doesn't work because I cannot refer to the instance I newed up in the testFilter Sub. 
DefaultFilterLine.Add
End Sub
```

DefaultFilterLine.Add doesn't work because the code uses frmFilter (which is it's default instance and has no model assigned to it). Therefore the question should probably be:

**How can one refer to a Userform Instance in another module (class module in this case) ?**

*Edit 2:*

This is the relevant code of frmFilter:

```
Public DisableEvents As Boolean

Private Type TView
    Model As FilterModel
    IsCancelled As Boolean
    IsBack As Boolean
End Type

Private this As TView

Public Property Get Model() As FilterModel
    Set Model = this.Model
End Property

Public Property Set Model(ByVal value As FilterModel)
    Set this.Model = value
    'Validate
End Property
```

Model is a property of the UserForm of the Type FilterModel. FilterModel (currently) only consists of a Integer N and a collection where all the FilterLine are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `Filter.Parent`.

As an example:

Create a class named `Class1`.
Add this code:

```
Public WithEvents Filter As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub Filter_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox Filter.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

`UserForm1` contains a single combo-box named `ComboBox1`.
Add this code to the form:

```
Private colEvents As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim MyEvents As Class1

    Set colEvents = New Collection
    Set MyEvents = New Class1

    Set MyEvents.Filter = Me.ComboBox1
    colEvents.Add MyEvents

End Sub
```

Open the form and double-click the combobox and it will tell you the name of the form.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but I don't get a .Parent property for my WithEvents MSForms.ComboBox. Does this depend on the Version of VBA?

Comment: Oke, I tested this and `Me.Filter.Parent.Name` yields the right UserFormName. Which is nice. So altough it doesn't say Filter has a `.Parent` property it has one. BUT and here comes the big BUT: If I now want to access `Me.Filter.Parent.Model` the object doesn't exist. So maybe I am calling the default instance of the `Filter.Parent` could that be the case?

Comment: Is `Model` a procedure within the `UserForm`? I added this code to the form:  `Public Sub Model(): MsgBox Me.Name: End Sub` and then changed the `MsgBox` code in my `DblClick` event to `Filter.Parent.Model` and it ran the code.

Comment: See Edit 2 Model is a property of the UserForm and of the custom type FilterModel. If a new FitlerModel gets created the constructor will set N=0 and the Collection to a new collection. But if the frmFilters defaults instance gets created the model is nothing. This will then cause parent.model to be empty. So I know now how to call the userform in which the comboBox is but it is obivousely not the one I indendet it to be in.

Comment: I can't see any `Collections` in your code or a reference to `N`?  Wouldn't it be better to have `IsCancelled` and `IsBack` as properties of `FilterModel` rather than as a `Type` that also contains the class?

Comment: Oke I solved it using a workaround. I added another property into My FilterLine Class which is Called `ParentForm` this property is set using `set FilterLine.ParentForm =Me` in the frmFilter UserForm. And this makes this stuff work. You also may be right about the `IsBack` and `IsCancle` Stuff, but I am jsut getting started using this MVP structure so as long as it works and as long as I am not using default instances anymore I am happy.